# trying to create a dictionary from a text file but

Tags: python, dictionary

so, I have text file (a paragraph) and I need to read the file and create a dictionary containing each different word from the file as a key and the corresponding value for each key will be an integer showing the frequency of the word in the text file. 
an example of what the dictionary should look like:

`{'and':2, 'all':1, 'be':1, 'is':3}` etc.

so far I have this,

```
def create_word_frequency_dictionary () :
filename = 'dictionary.txt'
infile = open(filename, 'r') 
line = infile.readline()

my_dictionary = {}
frequency = 0

while line != '' :
    row = line.lower()
    word_list = row.split()
    print(word_list)
    print (word_list[0])
    words = word_list[0]
    my_dictionary[words] = frequency+1
    line = infile.readline()

infile.close()

print (my_dictionary)

create_word_frequency_dictionary()
```

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation defines [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module as "High-performance container datatypes". Consider using `collections.Counter` instead of re-inventing the wheel.

```
from collections import Counter
filename = 'dictionary.txt'
infile = open(filename, 'r') 
text = str(infile.read())
print(Counter(text.split()))
```

**Update:**
Okay, I fixed your code and now it works, but Counter is still a better option:

```
def create_word_frequency_dictionary () :
    filename = 'dictionary.txt'
    infile = open(filename, 'r') 
    lines = infile.readlines()

    my_dictionary = {}

    for line in lines:
        row = str(line.lower())
        for word in row.split():
            if word in my_dictionary:
                 my_dictionary[word] = my_dictionary[word] + 1
            else:
                 my_dictionary[word] = 1

    infile.close()
    print (my_dictionary)

create_word_frequency_dictionary()
```

Comment: Using built-in classes like collections.Counter is the correct way to go here. Avoid defining your own data structures when identical data structures already exist. It makes code more readable because I'm already familiar with how collections.Counter works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using version of python which has Counter:

```
>>> import collections
>>> words = ["a", "b", "a", "c"]
>>> word_frequency = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> for w in words:
...   word_frequency[w] += 1
... 
>>> print word_frequency
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 1})
```

Comment: Defaultdict was added in 2.5 and Counter was added in 2.7. If you're using 2.5 or 2.6, use this Counter recipe: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/

Comment: Alright I edited my code with what you posted here and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `my_dictionary[words] = frequency+1` with `my_dictionary[words] = my_dictionary[words]+1`.

Comment: This won't work unless you're using a `collections.defaultdict(int)` or you use `my_dictionary.get(key, 0)`. Instead, you should use `collections.Counter` to store the frequency of each word list.